# How many bits are needed to address any single byte in memory if we have 520Kbits of memory?

Tags: memory, byte, memory-address, bit

I was doing a tutorial a few weeks ago and this was one of the questions. In my notes I only found examples of doing this with KBytes and MBytes but not with Kbits. I still completed this question but it was incorrect. Here's what I did:

`520 * 1024` (one kilobit is 1024 bits)

`= 532480 / 8` (8 bits is one byte)

`= 66560 bits`

I asked my lecturer and he just asked me to send him an email. He didnt help me at all so I am now asking here. Could someone please give me the correct answer and also how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 520 * 1024 = 532480 bits

therefore 66,560 bytes.

If 2^16=65,536 so 16 bits can address 65,536 bytes, but you have a bit more so you need 17 bits.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I was on the right track. Just the very final answer I didn't get. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have worked out correctly that you have 66560 *bytes* of memory. Assuming that a byte is the smallest individually-addressable unit of memory on your architecture, you need to work out how many bits you need to address 66560 memory locations.

Is 8 bits enough? With 8 bits, you can address 256 locations.

Is 16 bits enough?